# Plotting piecewise function

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a solution to a differential solution but the issue is that I have different solutions in different intervals.

For examle:

```
x_1(t) when t belongs to [0,t_1]  
x_2(t) when t belongs to [t_1,t_2]  
x_3(t) when t belongs to [t_2,t_3]
```

Now I need to plot these graphs so that they look like they have a single function i.e just immediately after the first graph `x_1(t)` until `t_1`, I need the other graph `x_2(t)` and so on.

Is it possible in Matlab?

Comment: have you tried just plotting all three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?s_tid=doc_ta) with multiple inputs to plot them altogether:

```
% the functions:
x_1 = @(t) 2.*t;
x_2 = @(t) 5.*t;
x_3 = @(t) 7.*t;
% the transition points:
t_1 = 30;
t_2 = 60;
t_3 = 90;
% plotting:
plot(0:t_1,x_1(0:t_1),t_1:t_2,x_2(t_1:t_2),t_2:t_3,x_3(t_2:t_3))
```

[image]

Another way, that lets you define all kind of function specific visual properties is to use [`hold`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html?s_tid=doc_ta):

```
f = @(t,a) a.*t;
t = 0:30:100;
m = 'os^'; % choosing different marker for each function
for k = 1:numel(t)-1
    plot(t(k):t(k+1),f(t(k):t(k+1),k),m(k))
    hold on
end
hold off
```

[image]

Comment: or just `plot([t1,t2,t3],[x1,x2,x3])` if different colors/styles are not desired